# Update a Salesforce consent via Cloudpage with a checkbox

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, html, cloudpage, unsubscribe

I am struggling trying to create a Cloudpage which update consent on Salesforce. When I try to publish the Cloudpage I do have this error :

"An error occurred while previewing this content.

This can happen for many reasons, including an incomplete or incorrect MC script (AMPscript, SSJS, or GTL) or missing subscriber context.

Click Cancel to review your code or Publish to send the updated content live"

**What I wanted to do in my Cloudpage ?**

1. I want to display a checkbox according to the market I declare in the email and update the consent associated to the market in Salesforce. The box has to appear checked.
2. If the subscriber let the box checked and click on the submit button, the consent will be updated.
3. If the suscriber uncheck the box and submit the form, then the consent will  not be updated.

**This is the code I had inserted in my cloud page :**

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="presentation" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper"><tr><td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"><script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
try{
</script>

%%[
var @market, @contactId, @consentId, @updateRecord

/*retrieve the value for market parameter from email*/
SET @market = RequestParameter('Market')
SET @contactId = _subscriberkey 


/* fetch data from Sales Cloud to show in the form */
   SET @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Consent__c","Id,OptIn_Email_Auto__c,OptIn_Email_Voyage__c","Contact__c", "=", @contactId)
  
IF RowCount(@subscriberRows) == 1 THEN
      SET @row = row(@subscriberRows,1)
      SET @ConsentId = field(@row,"Id")
ENDIF 

IF RequestParameter("submitted") == true THEN
 /* update Consent */ 
  SET @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
      "Consent__c", RequestParameter('cid'),
      "OptIn_Email_Auto__c", Iif(RequestParameter("EmailAuto") == "on", "true", "false"),
      "OptIn_Email_Voyage__c", Iif(RequestParameter("EmailVoyage") == "on", "true", "false")
ENDIF 

]%%
  
<script runat="server">
}catch(e){
 Write(Stringify(e));
}
</script>
<style>
.wrapper{
  padding-left: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #05425F;
  }
ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none
  }
.alignClass{
  text-align:center
  }
.isCursor{
  cursor:pointer;
  }
.buttonClass{
    background-color: #05425F;
    border-radius: 24px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:none;
    padding:8px;
    color: white;
    text-align:center;
  }
</style>
<div class="wrapper">
 <form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
   /*Input checkbox according to Market*/
 %%[ if @market == "Auto" then ]%%
<div> 
  <input type="checkbox" class="isCursor" name="EmailAuto" checked=""> 
  <label>Je confirme vouloir me désabonner de la réception des communications Auto </label>
  </div>
  %%[ELSEIF  @market == "Voyages" then ]%%
<div> 
  <input type="checkbox" class="isCursor" name="EmailVoyage" checked="">
  <label>Je confirme vouloir me désabonner de la réception des communications Voyages </label>
  </div>
  
%%[
ENDIF 

]%%
   <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="true"><br>
      <input name="cid" type="hidden" value="%%=v(@ConsentId)=%%"><br>
      <div style="display:flex;align-items:center">
       <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer les préférences" class="buttonClass">
        %%[ if @updateRecord == 1 then ]%%
         <p style="color:#639e30;margin-left:15px">Vos préférences ont bien été enregistrées.</p>
      %%[ elseif @updateRecord == 0 then ]%%
        <p style="color:#f7aa36;margin-left:15px">Échec de la mise à jour de vos préférences, Essayez à nouveau ultérieurement.</p>
      %%[ endif ]%%
      

</div></form></div>
</td></tr></table>
```

I had updated the code like this and the page is now published, the only thing is that the consent is not updated on false on Salesforce and the message that I have is that the failure answer of the update when clicking on submit that appears. Here is the code updated :

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="presentation" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper"><tr><td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"><script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
try{
</script>%%[
var @market, @contactId, @consentId, @updateRecord



/*retrieve values from email*/
SET @market = RequestParameter('Market')
SET @contactId = _subscriberkey
/* fetch data from Sales Cloud to show in the form */
SET @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Consent__c","Id,OptIn_Email_Auto__c,OptIn_Email_Voyage__c","Contact__c", "=", @contactId)



IF RowCount(@subscriberRows) == 1 THEN
SET @row = row(@subscriberRows,1)
SET @ConsentId = field(@row,"Id")
ENDIF



IF RequestParameter("submitted") == true THEN
/* update Consent */
SET @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
"Consent__c", RequestParameter('cid'),
"OptIn_Email_Auto__c", Iif(RequestParameter("EmailAuto") == "on", "false", "true"),
"OptIn_Email_Voyage__c", Iif(RequestParameter("EmailVoyage") == "on", "false", "true"))
ENDIF]%%
  
<script runat="server">
}catch(e){
Write(Stringify(e));
}
</script>
<style>
ul li{
display: inline-block;
list-style: none
}
.alignClass{
text-align:center
}
.isCursor{
cursor:pointer;
}
.buttonClass{
background-color: #05425F;
border-radius: 24px;
border:none;
padding:8px;
cursor:pointer;
color: white;
text-align:center;
}
</style>
<div style="padding-left:20px">
<form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
%%[ if @market == "Auto" then ]%%
<div>
<input type="checkbox" class="isCursor" name="EmailAuto" checked="">
<label>Je confirme vouloir me désabonner de la réception des communications Auto </label>
</div>
%%[ELSEIF @market == "Voyages" then ]%%
<div>
<input type="checkbox" class="isCursor" name="EmailVoyage" checked="">
<label>Je confirme vouloir me désabonner de la réception des communications Voyages </label>
</div>
%%[ ENDIF ]%%
  
<input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="true"><br>
<input name="cid" type="hidden" value="%%=v(@ConsentId)=%%"><br>
<div style="display:flex;align-items:center">
<input type="submit" value="Enregistrer mes préférences" class="buttonClass">
%%[ if @updateRecord == 1 then ]%%
<p style="color:#639e30;margin-left:15px">Vos préférences ont bien été enregistrées.</p>
%%[ elseif @updateRecord == 0 then ]%%
<p style="color:#f7aa36;margin-left:15px">Échec de la mise à jour de vos préférences, Essayez à nouveau ultérieurement.</p> %%[ endif ]%%
</div></form></div>
</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: How are you ensuring `_subscriberKey` exists and has a value?  You shouldn't execute any AMPscript functions without ensuring the inputs exists and have values.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs should I set the _subscriberKey value in my email ?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs in my code that the contact Id is the contactId in Salesforce and it exists in Salesforce

Comment: Please remove the screenshots.  You can format your code blocks with three ticks at the beginning and the end.

Comment: From where does a customer arrive at this page?   A link in an SFMC email?

Comment: Hi @AdamSpriggs, the customer arrives with a link I have put that on the redirection link in my email : %%[
%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL('779', '@Market', 'Auto'))=%%
]%%

Comment: When you paste your unsub URL from your inbox into wheregoes.com, what do you get?

Comment: Hi @AdamSpriggs, I have updated the code and the page display the checkbox according to the market, the only thing is when I publish the page, and I try on email, the Submit button seems to not work. It doesn't update the Consent on Salesforce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest taking the time to understand how the data is flowing to the page and then what you're doing with it on form submission.  Finding the issue can be as simple as adding debugging statements.

Here are some questions to ask yourself as you're troubleshooting:

- Do each of the variables have values before they're used in functions?
- Do all of the variables used in conditionals have expected values?
- What code executing on load or on post?
- Is the code indented to reveal the structure?
- Have you removed code in steps to a point where the page compiles and loads?

I didn't test this since I have no access to your org, but this illustrates the first four points above:

```ampscript
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1");
try {
</script>

    %%[

      set @debug = 1

      /*retrieve the value for market parameter from email*/
      set @submitted = RequestParameter("submitted")
      SET @market = RequestParameter('Market')
      SET @contactId = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")

      if @debug == 1 then   
        output(concat("<br>submitted: ", @submitted))
        output(concat("<br>market: ", @market))
        output(concat("<br>contactId: ", @contactId))
      endif 

      if not empty(@contactId) then

         /* fetch data from Sales Cloud to show in the form */
          SET @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Consent__c","Id,OptIn_Email_Auto__c,OptIn_Email_Voyage__c","Contact__c", "=", @contactId)

          set @rowCount = rowcount(@subscriberRows)
            
          if @debug == 1 then 
            output(concat("<br>rowCount: ", @market))
          endif 

          IF @rowCount == 1 THEN
                SET @row = row(@subscriberRows,1)
                SET @ConsentId = field(@row,"Id")
          ENDIF 

          if @debug == 1 then 
            output(concat("<br>ConsentId: ", @ConsentId))
          endif 

      else 

          if @debug == 1 then 
            output(concat("<br>missing values for contactId"))
          endif       

      endif 

      IF @submitted == "true" THEN

        /* update Consent on submit */ 
        set @cid = RequestParameter('cid')
        set @emailAuto = RequestParameter("EmailAuto")
        set @emailVoyage = RequestParameter("EmailVoyage") 

        if @debug == 1 then 
          output(concat("<br>cid: ", @cid))
          output(concat("<br>emailAuto: ", @emailAuto))
          output(concat("<br>emailVoyage: ", @emailVoyage))
        endif 

        set @emailAuto = Iif(@emailAuto == "on", "true", "false")
        set @emailVoyage = Iif(@emailVoyage == "on", "true", "false")

        if @debug == 1 then 
          output(concat("<br>emailAuto: ", @emailAuto))
          output(concat("<br>emailVoyage: ", @emailVoyage))
        endif 

        if not empty(@cid) and not empty(@emailAuto) and not empty(@emailVoyage) then

          SET @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
                "Consent__c", @cid,
                "OptIn_Email_Auto__c", @emailAuto,
                "OptIn_Email_Voyage__c",  @emailVoyage
              )
          
        else 

            if @debug == 1 then 
              output(concat("<br>missing values for update"))
            endif       

        endif 

      ENDIF 

    ]%%
  
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">
} catch(e) {
 Write("<br>e: " + Stringify(e));
}
</script><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

   <form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
   
      %%[ if @market == "Auto" then ]%%
      
        <input type="checkbox" class="isCursor" name="EmailAuto" checked=""> 
        <label>Je confirme vouloir me désabonner de la réception des communications Auto </label>
      
      %%[ elseif @market == "Voyages" then ]%%
        
        <input type="checkbox" class="isCursor" name="EmailVoyage" checked="">
        <label>Je confirme vouloir me désabonner de la réception des communications Voyages </label>

      %%[ else ]%%

         %%[
            if @debug == 1 then 
              output(concat("<br>market value is incorrect or empty"))
            endif 
         ]%%   
        
      %%[ endif ]%%

      <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="true"><br>
      <input name="cid" type="hidden" value="%%=v(@ConsentId)=%%"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer les préférences" class="buttonClass">
      
      %%[ if @submittted == 1 then ]%%

          %%[ if @updateRecord == 1 then ]%%
          
             <p style="color:#639e30;margin-left:15px">
              Vos préférences ont bien été enregistrées.
             </p>
          
          %%[ elseif @updateRecord == 0 then ]%%
          
            <p style="color:#f7aa36;margin-left:15px">
              Échec de la mise à jour de vos préférences, Essayez à nouveau ultérieurement.
            </p>

          %%[ endif ]%%

      %%[ endif ]%%

   </form>
        
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, you're missing a closing paren on your [UpdateSingleSalesforceObject](https://ampscript.guide/UpdateSingleSalesforceObject) function.

Comment: Hi @AdamSpriggs, the update worked perfectly with the debug tips. The consent ID was missed on my code. Thanks for your reply !